# Mocha not registering 'it' blocks inside promise list

Tags: promise, async-await, mocha.js

I'm trying to write a test that will run a GET over all items. To do this, I get that list in the `before` block, then I want to have an `it` block for each item. I am trying to do this by putting the `it` block inside `itemList.forEach`. However, I suspect that the problem here is that the blocks never get registered for the test. How can I run this test as desired?

```
let token;
let itemList;

describe('GET items/:itemId with Admin', async () => {
  before(async () => {
    // NOTE: item.find({}) returns a promise of a list of all items
    itemList = await item.find({});
    console.log(item[0]._id) // this logs correctly!
    const res = await userLogin(admin);
    token = res.body.accessToken.toString();   
  });

  it('registers initial it test', () => {
    // This test passes and logs the statement
    console.log('first test registered')
    console.log(itemList.length) // successfully logs non-zero value
  })

  await itemList.forEach(async (item) => {
    it('respond with json with a item', () => {
    const itemId = item._id;
    return getItem(itemId, token)
      .then((response) => {
        assert.property(response.body, '_id');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think `describe` takes a function that returns a promise.

Comment: [You cannot use `await` with `forEach`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I read that post before, but to be honest, I have an existing test suite that uses `async await` and `forEach` for a non-promise array and it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Also removing the async/await doesn't change the non-functional behavior of the test. Essentially I think the problem is that when mocha reads over the cases, `itemList` is `[]`, so it doesn't register any of the cases, even though `itemList` is populated as evident by the `console.log` statement

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the `before` setup runs before every `it` test. It doesn't run immediately, and definitely does not wait for anything until you try to iterate your `itemList`. I think you will need to do either

```
describe('GET items/:itemId with Admin', async () => {
  let token;
  before(async() => {
    const res = await userLogin(admin);
    token = res.body.accessToken.toString();   
  });

  // a list of all items for which tests should be created
  const itemList = await item.find({});
  console.log(itemList.length) // successfully logs non-zero value

  for (const item of itemList) {
    it('responds with json for item '+item, () => {
    const itemId = item._id;
    return getItem(itemId, token).then((response) => {
      assert.property(response.body, '_id');
    });
  }
});
```

or

```
describe('GET items/:itemId with Admin', () => {
  let itemList;
  let token;
  before(async() => {
    [itemList, token] = await Promise.all([
      item.find({}),
      userLogin(admin).then(res => res.body.accessToken.toString())
    ]);
  });

  it('responds with json for every item', () => {
    return Promise.all(itemList.map(item => {
      const itemId = item._id;
      return getItem(itemId, token)
        .then((response) => {
          assert.property(response.body, '_id');
        });
      });
    }));
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I ended up with. I ended up putting a new `describe` block in the `before` block. The `before` block results the promise that gives the list of items. There is an `it` block in the top level so that mocha registers the test in the first place.

```
describe('GET items/:itemId with Admin', async () => {
  before((done) => {
    Item.find({}).then(async (itemList) => {
      // create the admin user to get the items with
      await createUsers([admin]);
      const res = await userLogin(admin);
      const token = res.body.accessToken.toString();

      itemList.forEach((item, index) => {
        const itemId = item._id;
        describe(`get item number ${index}: _id: ${itemId}`, () => {
          it('responds with item id', () =>
            getItem(item, token)
              .expect(200)
              .then((response) => {
                assert.notProperty(response.body, 'error');
                assert.property(response.body, '_id');
                assert.equal(response.body._id, itemId);
              }));
        });
      });
      done();
    });
  });
  // If there is no it block here, it will not run the before block!
  it(`register the initial it`, () => {
    assert.equal('regression test!', 'regression test!');
  });
});
```